# why iview slider automatic decrease height of iview-caption div after one slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, iview-ui

iview slider automatically decreases the .iview-caption div height after every slide and  thats why my content cut last line. Please anybody Solve this problem.
Here is Code:-

```
<div id="iview">
    <div data-iview:thumbnail="slider/img/photo1.jpg" data-iview:image="slider/img/photo2.jpg">
        <div class="iview-caption" data-x="130" data-y="50" data-transition="expandRight">
            Can’t decide if you hate    your job or your boss more? 
        </div>

        <div class="iview-caption caption1" data-x="0" data-y="40" data-transition="fade" data-speed="2000">
           <span>Thinking of changing jobs? <a href="#"><strong>Register here</strong> </a>  for exciting  new job opportunities with Staffing.</span></div>
        </div>

        <div data-iview:thumbnail="slider/img/photo2.jpg" data-iview:image="slider/img/photo1.jpg">
            <div class="iview-caption" data-x="130" data-y="50" data-transition="expandRight" >
                Research shows that 78% of resumes are misleading.
            </div>
            <div class="iview-caption caption1" data-x="0" data-y="40" data-transition="fade" data-speed="2000">
                <span>Want to find the other 22%? We’ve already done that for you.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to see it somewhere?

Comment: Rishu: are you using the `iView` library for Vue.js?